# Nginx Server break images on web browser after refreshed 3 to 4 times

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, centos, configuration-files

Hi I am in very confusing state now. I have configured Nginx 1.6 on Centos 6 for serving only Code (js, css, html) pages all other images coming and calls happened through load balancer.

My problem is when I load the page on web browser the first time it will take time and then i refreshed the page 3 to 4 times the images/words are breaking such as `akki` shown as `__akki__` how do i know where its cached and how do i solve this problem my configuration as shown below

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  12;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    proxy_buffers 30 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
keepalive_timeout  65;
gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length  1024;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript te$
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
open_file_cache max=10000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid 60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on; 

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post result of `ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/`

Comment: `ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/
default.conf  ssl.conf  virtual.conf`

Comment: You have to trace exactly where goes problem request and provide us logs of this request handling. Probably when you will see that log entries you will find out problem yourself.